# Visual Studio hands when adding new file to source control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have been working in both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 with TFS 2015.

I will often have issues where, when I add a new file, the window pops up to add the file to TFS automatically, but it just sets there. I try to click Cancel, and it just sits there saying "Canceling...". I end up having to kill the process and reopen. It usually works for a little bit after that.

None of my coworkers, using the same versions of VS and TFS, have this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. It is starting to get exhausting to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear the version control cache on your machine. It should be located in:

`C:\Users\<yourusername>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\`. There will be numbered folders (6.0, 7.0, etc) in there, with Cache subfolders. Try deleting all of those.

It's going to be very difficult to give a definitive answer; the best anyone can give you are suggestions.

Comment: So the problems started again, though I got an actual error this time saying `The local data store is currently in use by another operation`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689212/constantly-get-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation-whe) in my searches which seems to have completely fixed my issue. Thanks again for the help.